# how to resize dialogue angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I was following this example [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/7kqyiW97CI696Ixn020g/) . How can I resize the model (pop up dialogou). I just wanted to know where to add height and width.

Comment: @yurzui thanks , this is exactly what i was looking for. i was trying this style in wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change style for `.modal-dialog` div in `modal.component.ts`:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 200px">
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/972WGoIIlXbjBeyEjydv?p=preview)

You can also set this value dynamically using `@Input` property

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
     ...
    <div class="modal-dialog" [style.width.px]="width">
     `
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @Input() width;
```

and then in your parent component:

```
<app-modal #modal1 [width]="200">
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/YRui3oYHajQURrnkRcHk?p=preview)**